# Dynamic Scenario Outline | Karate hangs when file not found

Tags: karate

Here is my sample feature file:

```
Feature: Test

Background:
  Given url testUrl
  And def data = read('classpath:test.txt')


Scenario Outline: Test scenario

  Given path 'test'
  And param parameter = <parameter>
  When method GET
  Then status 200

  Examples:
    | data |
```

Karate 0.9.1 hangs if test.txt is not found in dynamic scenario outline, because data in Examples: will be undefined.

I have been using Karate with parallel runner and gradle 4.7.

I will expect to fail this feature and move on to next one.

Comment: Try `And def data = read('classpath:test.txt')` you forgot `def` for data. but yeah it appears to be a issue in parser for 0.9.1

Comment: My bad. I forgot to put def in above sample. I have it in my actual feature file.Updated  issue description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please confirm if this is fixed in the develop branch, there were two related issues: [#686](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/686) and [#667](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/667).

Here are instructions to build from source: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: Yes. It works as expected with develop brach. It fails the scenario and move on.

Comment: Any tentative date for next release ?

Comment: @DJ342 we can do a dot release sooner if someone helps out with https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/685